# flash slideshow with vertical menue list and effects

Tags: flash, slideshow

at this site:

http://www.sbg.com.sa/index_a.html

I want to make a slideshow such as found in the header.

is there an application or software to make like it ?

note: I need one exactly like the url: http://www.sbg.com.sa/index_a.html

Answer (score 0):

This tile effect seems using a mixed frame animation with actionscript code. or only motion script. of course only actionscipt.

see a this tutorial: http://flash-effects.com/tag/transition/

may it help you :-)

Comment: thank you. but i prefer to get one exactly like the example. any help?